# Valid forms of exploratory data analysis for time series that don't assume stationarity?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, modeling, stationarity, exploratory-data-analysis

Lets say we are given a time series sample and want to try to create a model to forecast future values of said time series

When trying to build a model to forecast time series data, many statistics such as autocorrelation/partial autocorrelation and auto-mutual information/partial auto-mutual information can be calculated between lagged copies of the time series and the original series and, assuming stationarity of the process, can be used to to inform what lags of the time series can be helpful for forecasting future values of the time series.

However, if we are in a case where don't assume stationarity of the process, we lose the interpretation of these statistics even if they are still able to be calculated from the sample.

Are there any common methods for exploratory data analysis on time series data without the assumption of stationarity?

Because, as I understand it, these concepts such as autocorrelation, auto-mutual information, etc. require the assumption of stationarity because it allows us to, in a way, acquire multiple realizations of similar-to-i.i.d random variables from a single time series realization (e.g. $(X_{t-1}, X_t)$ for each observation in the time series sample) to which we can then apply conventional statistical methods that require i.i.d random variables (correlation, mutual information, etc.) and if we're not doing this, I'm not quite sure what that would look like.